# Set date value by manually and using date picker both in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, date

I have searched as much as possible and I got the solution for only one part of requirement not entire, so please read my scenario carefully and then proceed with it.

**Scenario**

I have some Edit Text fields in my iOS application, among which I have to allow users to either enter manually date in field or on click open date picker and select date from there.

**Requirement**

I have done both part separately as User can enter date manually or user can select date from date picker, but the requirement is both should work together, as

When user click on edit text date picker should open and if user want to enter manually then can able to enter manually.

**Note**

Please note that I have to use only edit text control, means Client has reject suggestion for using small date icon beside edit text and open date picker from there, client just wants to see both operation from one control only.

**So** please help me for this how can I do this, as currently on click every time date picker open and user is not able to enter data manually.

Comment: Add a long press gesture on text field to open the date picker. Single tap to edit form keyboard, long press to open date picker.

Comment: Also, for above approach to work, you will have to iterate through all gestures in text field and require them to fail if a long press is detected using `requireGestureRecognizerToFail`.

Answer (score 2):

If you still not get answer then check my below task.

**I have same requirement for selecting name from drop down instead of date picker. So you can apply same on your requirement.**

**First Take Edit text**

Initially you have to take simple edit text and apply on touch listener, now you have to check that when text length is 0(Zero) then keep date picker open to select date.

Now, if user will select date from picker then set same in edit text. But if date picker is open or close, when user start to enter text, at that time just check and if length of edit text is greater then zero then hide picker else show picker.

So this will work on both way like by adding or by selecting.

**Here, you just have to keep one thing in mind is date manually entered must be in same format as you are setting from picker.**

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

At first, Date picker control made by you is located under a textfield.
Then, as default, you make the datepicker hide.

For example,

```
Outlet UITextField *yourDateField;
```

And ...

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if(yourDateField == textField)
        [datepicker setHidden:NO];

    return YES;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([[touch view] class] != [UITextField class]) {
        [datepicker setHidden:YES];
        // hide keyboard
        return;

    }

}
```

Of course, when user selects the date from datepicker, you must ...

```
[yourDateField setText:<< datepicker's selected date  >>]
```